# How to send multiple commands to sftp using one line

Tags: scripting, sftp

The following command sends one command to `sftp` using one line:

```
sftp -o PasswordAuthentication=no user@host" <<<"lcd /home"
```

How to send multiple lines to `sftp` using one line. Is there a way to insert carriage returns or something to achieve this, for example:

```
sftp -o PasswordAuthentication=no user@host" <<<"lcd /home\n cd /myhome\n get file"
```

The idea is to NOT use the `sftp -b` option where an external file listing commands is loaded.

Answer (score 17):

From the here-string (`<<<`) syntax you used I guess your shell is `bash`, so you can also use string with backslash-escaped characters (`$''`):

```
sftp -o PasswordAuthentication=no user@host <<< $'lcd /home\n cd /myhome\n get file'
```

The portable alternative is here-document:

```
sftp -o PasswordAuthentication=no user@host <<END
lcd /home
cd /myhome
get file
END
```

Comment: `<<<` was introduced first by zsh (though inspired by `rc`) and was later added to ksh93 and then bash.

Comment: Thank you, @StephaneChazelas. I really need to strengthen my `zsh` skills.

Answer (score 12):

Use the `-b/--batchfile` option to have proper error handling:

```
 printf '%s\n' 'lcd /home' 'cd /myhome' 'get file' | sftp -b - user@host
```

Comment: To use variables change ' to "

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can just use `echo -e`

```
echo -e "lcd /home\ncd /myhome\nget file" | sftp user@host
```

Comment: `echo` is very non-standard - `echo -e` doesn't work the same everywhere, so you'd have to check first.  Alternatively, just use `printf` which is much more portable and should work the same everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

It is not necessary to avoid the `-b` option to avoid writing the batch file to disk.  Using [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html) you can create the batch on the fly.

```
batch() {
  echo lcd /home
  echo cd /myhome
  echo get file
}

sftp -b <(batch) -o PasswordAuthentication=no user@host
```

Answer (score 1):

Mybru, you can mos pipe your commands like so:

```
echo '
    lcd /home
    cd /myhome
    get file
' | sftp -o PasswordAuthentication=no user@host
```

Answer (score 0):

Use native sftp command

> sftp -o PasswordAuthentication=no user@host:/home/myhome/file

Comment: What you didn't notice was that `lcd` and `cd` do different things. You've just combined the paths into something that will not exist.